# Objective C - UIActivityIndicatorView positioning

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a UIActivityIndicatorView that I create and position in loadView function.

It works fine except that I can see for a split second the UIActivityIndicatorView on the top left corner before reposition itself to the center of the screen.

Why does it do that? And how can I prevent that?

I also try creating the UIActivityIndicatorView in viewDidLoad function and the same thing happens.

BTW, I'm using UIActivityIndicatorView as an example, but I also have a UIImageView that I alpha 0 and I also see it for a split second before it goes away.

Please enlight.

Thank you,
Tee

Comment: Are you setting the center of the activity view yourself? At what point are you doing it?

Comment: Hi Phil, I set the center of activity right after I create the UIActivityIndicatorView and before I call addSubview and startAnimating.

Comment: and what are you setting it to? the explicit center of the (to-be) superview?

Comment: That's correct. Code is like this. 
CGRect spinnerFrame = spinner.frame;
spinnerFrame.origin.x = (self.view.bounds.size.width - totalWidth) / 2.0;
spinnerFrame.origin.y = (self.view.bounds.size.height - spinnerFrame.size.height) / 2.0;
spinner.frame = spinnerFrame;
[self.view addSubview:spinner];

Comment: That's weird. I presume spinnerFrame.size has correct looking values at the time you use it in that code?

Comment: Yeah all values are right at that time. I think I'm going to just try do it through interface builder.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint right before the `addSubview:` and take a look at the frame values, what do you get? If you continue after that, is it still visible top left for a split second or is it at the right position immediately?

Answer (score 8):

Try adding it to the view before you change its position:

```
[self.view addSubview:spinner];
spinner.center = self.view.center;
```